meta_query post_date not returning results
I'm working on a query where I have a few conditions, one of them involving post_date. However, whenever I try to write my query, post_date doesn't return any matches. If I comment that part out, it will return matches (but not quite to where I need). If I only have the post_date query uncommented, it returns 0 results.
Is anyone able to help point me in the right direction?
$date_seven = date('Y-m-d H:i:s', strtotime('-7 days'));
'meta_query' => array(
                'relation' => 'AND', 
                // show posts where location is US
                array(
                    'key' => 'monitor_settings_location',
                    'value' => 'US',
                    'compare' => 'LIKE'
                ),
                    array(
                    'relation' => 'OR',
                    // if end date is empty, show for 7 days after publish date
                    array(
                        'relation' => 'AND',
                        array(
                            'key' => 'monitor_settings_end_date',
                            'value' => '',
                        ),
                        array(
                            'key' => 'post_date',
                            'value' => $date_seven,
                            'compare' => '>=',
                            'value' => 'DATETIME'
                        )
                        ),
                        // if end date exists, show until that date
                        array(
                            'key' => 'monitor_settings_end_date',
                            'value' => $date_now,
                            'compare' => '>='
                            'value' => 'DATETIME'
                        )
                )
            )

Using var_dump on the results with the post_date aspect commented out gives me public 'post_date' => string '2024-06-28 12:29:52' (length=19)

post_date isn't a meta key, it's an intrinsic part of the WordPress WP_Post object. You can use a date_query array in WP_Query to restrict the query by post date. See date parameters for more.

Does date_query work with a multi-level query? I only want it to use the post_date if monitor_settings_end_date is empty and monitor_settings_location matches the field

In that case you'd write two sets of arguments and then use the correct one after conditionally checking monitor_settings_end_date and monitor_settings_location.  ie. if( empty( 'monitor_settings_end_date ) && 'monitor_settings_location' == $value_to_match ) :  do the date_query version and then in an else : do the non-date_query version.
